# PSQLException not getting caught

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, sqlexception

I am using Tomcat 6 and Postgresql 8.4. My code looks as follows:

```
try {
  // Prepared statement inserting something...
} catch (final PSQLException e) {
  LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Saving failed.", e);
} catch (final SQLException e) {
  LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Saving failed (SQL).", e);
}
```

This insert into DB may cause a PSQLException (e.g. a unique key violation) which I want to catch with the first `catch`. However, what I actually find in the log is this:

```
SEVERE: Saving failed (SQL).
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UZIVATELIA_U_LOGIN"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at cz.ecoremedia.realpad.web.backend.Users.saveNewUser(Users.java:119)
    at cz.ecoremedia.realpad.web.backend.Users.saveUser(Users.java:237)
    at org.apache.jsp.User_jsp._jspService(User_jsp.java:159)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

If I check the type of `e` I caught, for example like this:

```
} catch (final SQLException e) {
  LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getClass().getName());
  LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Saving failed (SQL).", e);
```

It still tells me it was `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`.

When I try this locally in my Eclipse, it works perfectly - `PSQLException` gets caught correctly in the first `catch` block.

If I understand the problem correctly, the `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException` I catch is a different class from the `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException` that actually gets thrown. How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: You have a classloader problem. where is the postgres driver? I'm guessing it's not in your application under /WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: @NathanHughes how did you come to that conclusion? Postgres managed to figure out 'ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "' which would not be possible without the driver?

Comment: @Osama: i didn't say the driver wasn't there somewhere. i just guessed it's loaded in a different classloader. just a guess.

Comment: @NathanHughes Classloader would have been my guess too, but there is a `postgresql-8.4-703.jdbc4.jar` in my `WEB-INF/lib`. However, I just found another JDBC driver: `postgresql-9-1.0-801.jdbc4.jar` in Tomcat's `lib/` folder. This might be it, I'll try deleting the Tomcat's version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I had another JDBC driver in my Tomcat's `lib/` folder, apart from the one in `WEB-INF/lib/`. Removing the Tomcat's one fixed my problem.

(Yes, it was a different class loader problem, thanks @NathanHughes.)