# Spring @ControllerAdvice annotation

Tags: spring

I have a problem. I used @ControllerAdvice annotation, I can't catch PSQLException Exception. Please help me.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(PSQLException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public Result handlePSQLException(PSQLException ex) {
        Result r = new Result();
        r.setStatus(Result.ERROR);
        logger.error(r.updateMessage("Unable to complete operation"), ex);
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use Exeption instead of PSQLException it's works fine

Comment: Can you check the type of exception received when you use `Exception`

Comment: Yes I can check it, but my mind it is no good style, I don't wont write a lot of "if-else"

Comment: no, what I want is to identify the actual type of exception thrown

Comment: like add a `System.out.println(ex.getClass())` and see what is printed

Comment: I think @ArunPJohny meant for debugging purposes. Probably, the exception is not of the type you think it is.

Comment: that is why I doubt spring is wrapping the `PSQLException` with its own exception, so you need to identify the actual type of exception then we can proceed from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks that you are using different versions of driver jars or you are using same exception name but in different package check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742577/psqlexception-not-getting-caught) too